# CarrierWave Add ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile After Model Processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, image-uploading

I have an `Image` model that requires me to have some data set up before I can save the image, because I determine where to upload the image to and what to name it depending on some data from the model. Right now I'm trying to do:

```
# ImagesController sets up data
img = Image.new
img.imageable = user
phashion_img = Phashion::Image.new(file.path)
img.image_hash = phashion_img.fingerprint.to_s
img.batch = img.latest_batch + 1
img.extension = 'jpg'
img.height = 640
img.width = 640

# ImageUploader uses it
version :original do
  def full_filename
    "#{model.image_hash}/orig/#{alnum_encode(model.imageable.id)}.#{model.extension}"
  end
end
```

I've run into an issue trying to pass the uploaded image into the uploader.

`img.uploader.store! file` gives me the error `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`
`img.uploader.store! file.tempfile` gives me `You are not allowed to upload "" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png`

For reference, `file` is:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000109ccdb70 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/lx/xk8vzr4s0fdd_m5w0syftfl80000gn/T/RackMultipart20140723-28731-1b5weu8>, @original_filename="20140522_164844.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[images_attributes][0][uploader]\"; filename=\"20140522_164844.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">
```

Which would make file.tempfile:

```
#<Tempfile:/var/folders/lx/xk8vzr4s0fdd_m5w0syftfl80000gn/T/RackMultipart20140723-28731-1b5weu8>
```

Is there any way I could pass either of these objects, `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` or `Tempfile`, to the Carrierwave uploader? Some transformation I can do to them so that the uploader can accept one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my use case is so far off from what is intended with CarrierWave, or any of the other image upload gems out there, I ended up rolling my own solution using the AWS-SDK gem to upload to S3. It's pretty specific, but I'm posting the gist of it on the off chance that it helps someone else.

```
# Image processing
magick = Magick::Image.from_blob( file.read )[0]

if !["JPG", "JPEG", "GIF", "PNG"].include? magick.format
  # Invalid format specified
end

orig = Image.new
orig.imageable = user
phashion_img = Phashion::Image.new(file.path)
orig.image_hash = phashion_img.fingerprint.to_s
orig.batch = orig.latest_batch + 1
orig.extension = magick.format.downcase
filename = "#{orig.image_hash}/orig/#{Alnum.encode(orig.imageable_id)}.#{orig.extension}"
orig.height = magick.rows
orig.width = magick.columns
orig.size = 'orig'

# Upload to S3
s3 = AWS::S3.new
uploaded_name = Rails.root.to_s+filename.gsub('/', '_')
magick.write( uploaded_name ) # Save file to filesystem so I can upload to S3
s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[filename].write( open(uploaded_name), :acl => :public_read )
FileUtils.rm uploaded_name # Remove so it's not taking up space

# Crop
cropped = magick.crop(x.to_i, y.to_i, w.to_i, h.to_i, true) # Discard offset data to avoid borders

# Create Profile
# Resize_from is my own custom function to copy everything 
# but the size into another object and resize the image
resize_from(s3, orig, cropped, 640, 640)

# Create Grid
resize_from(s3, orig, cropped, 220, 220)

# Create Thumbnail
resize_from(s3, orig, cropped, 72, 72)
```